# Creating function for Haskell structure whose constructors are hidden

Tags: haskell

is there any way I can create a function for a structure whose constructors are hidden by the module containing it?

In my case, I want to add functions that operate on a `Data.IntSet.IntSet` and I need to pattern match on the constructors. It would also be nice to have access to the functions which are not in the export list of the module. Is this possible?

Here is something illustrating the general principle of what I want to do (not what I actually want to do, but it illustrates it):

```
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet

isTip :: IntSet.IntSet -> Bool
isTip (IntSet.Tip _) = True
isTip _ = False
```

Trying to load this in GHCi gives:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘IntSet.Tip’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I do realize that this can be risky if the internal implementation changes, but I just want to try out some stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The [true-name](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/true-name) package ("A Template Haskell hack to get unexported Names") looks helpful for playing in this way. One of the [examples in GitHub](https://github.com/liyang/true-name/blob/e4f971622dd09bbd357c3eef318ed6c212eec1d8/sanity.hs) actually involves `IntSet`.